# Yum install for users on small network

Tags: linux, script, yum

We have a small network of 15 users. I need to install some new libraries using yum on all computers on the network. I already have a csh script which allows me rsh onto all computers on the system so I could manually switch to root and install the required dependencies for each rsh. Is there a more effective means of doing this?

I have tried to do this using the following csh script. I have continued to use rsh for the moment while testing. However the script dies as soon as I rsh to another host file. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ($1 == "")then
    echo -n "Please enter a package to install\n"
    set package=$<
else set package = $#argv
endif

set numlines = `cat $NM_HOME/sh_local/nc_network2.txt | grep -v "^#" | fgrep "%" |  wc -l`
while ($numlines>0)
    set line = `cat $NM_HOME/sh_local/nc_network2.txt | grep -v "^#" | fgrep "%" | tail -$numlines | head -1`
    set host2 = `echo $line | cut -f 1 -d %`
    set where = `echo $line | cut -f 2 -d %`
    if ($host2 == $this_machine) then 
    echo "This is $host2....skipping rsh to this machine"
    echo ""
    goto yum
    endif
    echo ""
    echo "logging into $host2 $where"
    echo ""
    sleep 1
    rsh $host2
    yum:
    echo ""
    echo "Preparing to install $package on $host2"
    sudo yum -y install $package
    if ($host2 == $this_machine) then 
    goto decrement
    else
    logout
    goto decrement
    endif

    decrement:
    @ numlines--

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use ssh with public-key authentication to avoid typing passwords and to keep some sort of security.
2. Log in directly as root or run `sudo yum`.
3. Make sure yum is run noninteractively as `yum -y` so that the installation can run unattended.
4. Have a list of hosts in a file and run the installation in parallel on all hosts using GNU `parallel`[(gnu.org)](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) or `xargs`.
5. If you liked the automation look into tools for automated administration like `puppet`[(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29).